# PHP MySQL how to set column/field names into variables after fetch_assoc

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to get column names and the values, and then set the column names into variables... Does it make sense?

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password', 'db_name');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $column1 = $row['column1']; // <- can these be
    $column2 = $row['column2']; // as simple as one
    ...
    $column100 = $row['column100']; // line or two?
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Can anyone guide me how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: _“Does it make sense?”_ - without an explanation _why_ you’d want that – rather little. “Numbered” variable names is something you should generally try and stay away from - that’s what we _have_ arrays for to begin with.

Comment: The reason is the numbers of the column (many columns in many tables) and the code looks so long and tedious to declare each variables.

Comment: No, I wanted to know why you (think you) need this in “variables with numbers in their names” in the first place. You already _have_ this data in a nice array in $row, so what exactly is stopping you from using _that_ to access your data?

Comment: Actual column names are like, ID, product_code, product_name, product_date, product_category1_id, product_category2_id, ... and so on.. I have no idea how to fix this database structure and the codes.. At least I could manage to shorten the codes with extract :) Thanks

Comment: That still doesn’t explain why you think having a lot of individual variables floating around had any advantage over directly accessing the values inside your array. If `$row['foo']` and `$row['bar']` exist, why would you insist on having `$foo` and `$bar` available individually? Especially if the number of columns is actually going into hundreds …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string to declare a variable, called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value)
        $$key = $value;
//      ^----------------------notice the double dollar
}
```

Or, you can use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    extract($row);
}
```

---

To make sure you don't want to overwrite some variables already existing, you can prefix them.

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value)
        $someNicePrefix_{$key} = $value;
//                      ^----^-------------notice the curly brackets
}
```

Using extract, you can add more parameters (described in the documentation linked above)

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    extract($row, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "someNicePrefix");
}
```

Both methods will have the same effect. Notice that for extract, a character `_` will be inserted between prefix and variable name

Comment: This has potential for a massive eff-up, if one of the database columns ever “collides” with the name of a variable already existing in the script. Imagine one of the columns was named `row` or `res` …

Comment: Hi Cid, thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to do.
Hi misorude, that's right.. I'm now having troubles with multiple IDs. I wonder if I can add the table name before the variable variables.

Comment: Thank you very much, Cid :) The extract version works perfectly!